# Parse string with characters and numbers in android

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, int

I have the following string with characters, numbers and also extra non-numeric characters. I managed to replace the non-numeric characters. But I am lost with characters and numbers at the end.I am getting this string from the following method. I use this method to remove the non-numeric.

```
String[] stringArray = string.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("[^ A-Za-z0-9]","").trim().split(",");
```

results with `"I7f253e0", "I6fc2699"`. How can I parse this ?

```
public static int[] string_to_int_arr(String string){

    String[] stringArray = string.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("[^ A-Za-z0-9]","").trim().split(",");

    int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
        try {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"" + e);
        }
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Comment: Remove all your manipulations and use Arrays.toString(myarray)

Comment: manipulations ? you mean. can you be more specific please :)

Comment: Are you sure it's normal to have this kind of String in the first place? This looks like an object reference. I can't see what anyone could do with a modified string of a reference

Comment: The string you use at the beginning , what is it ? where does it come from ? It shouldn't be like this

Comment: @azro i've just updated my question. please have a look

Comment: That still doesn't give an answer to "are you sure that the kind of String to expect?". It adds even more questions. Like why does loging `"string1"+ String1` gives `[I@7f253e0`. How does the part "string1"`` disappear? Is the`targ(String[] string)` parameter correctly filled (i.e not filled with with a `myArray.toString()`)

Comment: It is still not clear where this strings come from or if the numbers you are trying to parse are really the data you need. It looks like as if you are doing `String x = MyClass.toString()` but your MyClass dosen't overide a toString method.

Comment: @jhamon I am trying to fill the `targ(String[] string)` array with the values. and extract the string stored in `string[8 + i]` index. And convert the string to int array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will help, but anyway, if you want to remove all non digits just do the following:

```
String x = "[I@7f253e0";
String y = x.replaceAll("\\D", "");
System.out.println(y);

//72530
```

Comment: Although this works, this is not the correct answer, because the 72530 has nothing to do with the original int array.